# React - socket.io on() does not seem to do anything

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

So I have this react component which connects to the express server on port 3000. The express server does work and logs "someone connected" and "user disconnected" when they load in the lobby component. However, the on() bit in the client-side does not seem to do anything. I never get the "connected to backend" message to log in client console. From what I can see, I don't get errors and it does connect to the correct namespace(from the express logs). Not sure why this is not working.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import "./LobbyComponent.css";

function Lobby() {   

    useEffect(() => {
        handleSocket();
    }, []);

    const handleSocket = () => {
        const lobby = io('http://localhost:3000/lobby');
        lobby.on('connection', function (socket){
            console.log('connected to backend');

            socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                console.log('disconnected: ', socket);
            });   

        });  
        lobby.on('chat message', function(msg){
            console.log('message: ', msg);
        });

    };   

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )

}

export default Lobby;
```

server.js file

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let server = require('http').Server(app);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Listening at:", PORT);
});


let io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

const chatNameSpace = io.of('/lobby');

chatNameSpace.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('chat message', 'everyone');

    console.log('someone connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake. It annoys me a bit that the client and server side uses two different names for the event. I'll leave this if anyone else is as blind as me.

It should be:

```
lobby.on('connect', function (){
    console.log('connected: ');
});
```

not:

```
lobby.on('connection', function (){
    console.log('connected: ');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect from front to back when initializing:

```
const socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_HOST, {
  forceNew: true,
});
```

Comment: So that really didn't matter. As `useEffect()` is functional components lifecycle "replacement". So it IS connected. 

Moved the `lobby.on('chat message')` outside of the `on('connection')` and I do get the message if I send it to everyone.

Should I expect `on('connection')` to fire when it is being connected? because right now it is not. But it does receive messages however.

Updated my question with the code that works a bit.

Comment: I figured it out.... The client side on() I should have used is: 'connect' not 'connection'